# SQL AVG applied to more than one by group?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate a column average by group for several groups in the same query.

Assume there are 2 columns (a,b), for each I want the average of another column (c) per group of the first column. For example, this would return the a groups and average c value per a group.

```
SELECT a, AVG(c)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY a
```

This gives me two columns.

| a | AVG(c) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 0.75 |

I want a table like with two columns per grouping column like this.

| a | AVG(c) | b | AVG(c) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.5 | 8 | 1.5 |
| 2 | 0.75 | 9 | 0.25 |

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide sample data as you provided the desired result?

Comment: Get 2-column rowset from the server and convert it to 4-column form on the client using its reporting subsystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more simply done in separate rows with `union all`:

```
SELECT 'a' as which, a, AVG(c)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY a
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' as which, b, AVG(c)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY b;
```

If you really want them side-by-side, the query is quite a bit more complicated:

```
SELECT MAX(a) as a, MAX(a_avg_c) as a_avg_c,
       MAX(b) as b, MAX(b_avg_c) as b_avg_c
FROM ((SELECT a, AVG(c) as a_avg_c, null as b, null as b_avg_c,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a) as seqnum
       FROM mytable
       GROUP BY a
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT null, null, b, AVG(c) as b_avc_c,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY b) as seqnum
       FROM mytable
       GROUP BY b
      )
     ) ab
GROUP BY seqnum;
```

This is more complicated because SQL treats a row as a single *entity*.  You actually want columns on each row that are entirely unrelated to each other.  So, this version creates a "relation" by assigning a sequential value and then aggregating by that value to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `analytical function` and `distinct` as follows:

```
Select distinct a,
       Avg(c) over (partition by a) as a_avg,
       B,
       Avg(c) over (partition by b) as b_avg
  From your_table t
```